# Snipping Tool saves screen shots to random temp folder - how is this useful and how can it be changed?

Tags: windows, screenshot, windows-11

If I configure the Snipping Tool (11.2109.37.0) to "Save snips" it doesn't let me configure the path, or even tell me what it is.

Using the Everything search tool, I determined that they are ending up in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`, which - how is this useful to me that they are in a location that has a randomized name, that is temporary, and that is really inconvenient for me to access. Is something wrong?

Either way, can you modify the location where screen shots are stored?

[image: Save Snip Setting]

Comment: It seems you're talking about the Snip & Sketch app, not the old Snipping Tool. You should edit the question title.

Comment: @kreemoweet I understand the history of the app replacement but the fact of the matter is that the word Sketch never appears in Windows 11.  If you run the (one and only) program, it says "Snipping Tool" in the title bar of the app. If you search the app store for Snip & Sketch, and click Open, it opens the same tool, titled Snipping Tool. So while it is confusing (though not as confusing as the two OneNotes), I think this is the most accurate still.

Answer (score 1):

> If I configure the Snipping Tool (11.2109.37.0) to "Save snips" it
> doesn't let me configure the path, or even tell me what it is.
> Can you modify the Save location?

Yes.  You can Save and adjust the path where the file will he saved.

Depends on Windows 10 or 11.

This is for Snipping Tool (Windows 11) version 11.2109.37.0 and Snip 'n Sketch (Windows 10) version 10.2008.2277.0).  There is only one tool and one name in each OS (all up to date) and Microsoft changes the name. Just find the Snipping tool in your system.

For Windows 10, the Save button is on the Snip 'n Sketch menu bar. For Windows 11, you click on the 3 dots (...) top right to see the Save menu.

Then click on Save and a File Explorer box opens and it is at that point where you can change the path it has chosen.

A bit picky but it works fine.

[image: Change Snip n Sketch file save path]

.

From that point Snip n sketch will save to the last folder